# Cannot mount SD Card after Update Raspbian

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I have updated my raspbian installation on my raspberry pi and something seems to have gone wrong. the rpi does not start anymore and what's worse I cannot even mount the SD card.

`lsblk` shows the sd card once I plug it in:

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk  
├─sda1                    8:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot
└─sda5                    8:5    0 118,8G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt          252:0    0 118,8G  0 crypt
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:1    0   115G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:2    0   3,8G  0 lvm   
      └─cryptswap1      252:3    0   3,8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sdb                       8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                    8:17   0 931,5G  0 part  
sdc                       8:32   1    15G  0 disk  
├─sdc1                    8:33   1    63M  0 part  /media/xxxxxxxx/boot
└─sdc2                    8:34   1  14,9G  0 part
```

so does `fdisk -l`:

```
Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1         8192   137215   129024   63M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2       137216 31422463 31285248 14,9G 83 Linux
```

Gparted (sometimes) finds the SD card on `/dev/sdc`, however, it cannot format the drive - especially sdc2 seems to be a problem. When trying to check and repair sdc2, it says:

```
e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/sdc2
```

running `e2fsck` directly on `/dev/sdc2` gives me the following:

```
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sdc2: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Run journal anyway<y>? yes
e2fsck: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/sdc2

/dev/sdc2: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

did somebody experience similar problems?

if so I would be grateful for hints.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdc2` shows you Copies from the Superblock of the Partition. 
For example `32768, 98304, 163840, 229376`
`sudo e2fsck -y -b 98304 /dev/sdc2`

And put money aside for a new card.

Comment: If he cannot write on it, most probably trying to correct the original superblock with a copy wont work too. Would you flesh out better the idea of buying another card?